# Request from Angular to Spring Gateway fails CORS error

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, cors, spring-cloud

The project uses Spring-Security OAUTH 2. An Angular application is used as a web client. And as a Keycloak authorization server.
The Angular application sends requests to the Spring application via the Spring GateWay.

When I try to send a Get request, I get an error

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

file Pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.amrut.prabhu</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-keycloak-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring Cloud Gateway Oauth2 With Keycloak</name>
    <description>spring cloud gateway with keycloak oauth2</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
        <logback-access-spring-boot-starter.version>3.1.2</logback-access-spring-boot-starter.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, ServerLogoutSuccessHandler handler) {
        http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()           
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/actuator/**", "/","/logout.html")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .oauth2Login() // to redirect to oauth2 login page.
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(handler)
        ;

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerLogoutSuccessHandler keycloakLogoutSuccessHandler(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository repository) {

        OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler =
                new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(repository);

        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}/logout.html");

        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }    
}
```

I tried to register in the Spring Gateway properties file, from this post
[cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61189793/spring-gateway-request-blocked-by-cors-no-acces0control-allow-orgin-header)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
              allowedOrigins: "*"
              allowedMethods: "*"
              allowedHeaders: "*"
```

I also tried to determine the global configuration of CORS, according to this article

[baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-cors)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class CorsGlobalConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .allowedMethods("PUT")
            .allowedMethods("GET")
            .allowedHeaders("Baeldung-Allowed", "Baledung-Another-Allowed")
            .exposedHeaders("Baeldung-Allowed", "Baeldung-Exposed")
            .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

I still get an error
What am I doing wrong?
I add all the necessary headers.
What else does he need?
And the @CrossOrigin annotation on the method always worked before.

The following two options also did not help solve the problem:

```
@Configuration   
public class CorsWebFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        corsConfig.setMaxAge(8000L);
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        // corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("Baeldung-Allowed");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource(new PathPatternParser());
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }    
}
```

OR

```
@Configuration
public class CorsWebFilterConfig implements WebFilter {
        
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange,
                             WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
    
                                    ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();
        ServerHttpResponse response = serverWebExchange.getResponse();
        HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "http://localhost:4200");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, "true");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "*");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, "*");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE, "18000L");
        if (request.getMethod() == HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
            return Mono.empty();//HERE
        }
        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
        }    
    }
```

The annotation on the method does not work either

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

Here are the contents of the network tab, the first request is OPTIONS, the second is GET

```
Request URL: http://10.151.68.8:8484/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=spring-gateway-client&scope=message.write&state=dnAY-OwNUBGKuvZE5-3AH3L6v9W8OA5V67bD-U2YgiA%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9090/login/oauth2/code/keycloak
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.151.68.8:8484
Referrer Policy: no-referrer

    Response
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2022 07:34:59 GMT
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

    Request
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 10.151.68.8:8484
Origin: null
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

For some reason, the Origin = null field in the request
Perhaps this is the reason for cors?
It turns out that Gateway sends a verification request to the authorization server with Origin = null and receives a cors error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that as a result of double forwarding of requests, the origin field became null. And when Keycloak received such a request, it threw a cors error. I found a temporary solution to this problem (thanks to the user @ch4mp):
I disable oauth2 on the gateway

```
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>        -->
```

in the properties file I write

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        add-to-simple-url-handler-mapping: true
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowed-origins: "*"
            allowed-methods: "*"
            allowed-headers: "*"
            exposed-headers: "*"
```

and I add two beans

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, Function<GatewayFilterSpec, UriSpec> brutalCorsFilters) {
    return builder
           .routes()
           .route(p -> p.path("/users/**").filters(brutalCorsFilters).uri("https://localhost:9443"))
           .route(p -> p.path("/greet/**").filters(brutalCorsFilters).uri("https://localhost:9445"))
           .build();
}

@Bean
Function<GatewayFilterSpec, UriSpec> brutalCorsFilters() {
    return f -> f
            .setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
            .setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
}
```

The solution is temporary, but I haven't found another one. And what offers baeldung.com it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My hints are:

- check what are the headers of your requests/responses in your browser
- the gateway cors config could contain these as well:

```
    cors()
    .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and()...

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
      CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
      // other settings of configuration
      configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
      UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
      return source;
      }
```

Maybe you checked the following link, but if not then worth a try in case the code above did not help:  https://reflectoring.io/spring-cors/

Comment: None of your options worked for me. Do they really work for you, in relation to Spring-Gateway?

Comment: Yes, I copied the lines from my project.
Could you update your question with the headers of the request and response?